# failed to load org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ContainerLocalizer

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I enable the HDFS/Yarn security mode, and when I run my project, it always reports

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ContainerLocalizer
>   at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:505)
> at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:418)
> at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell
>   ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:650)
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor.startLocalizer(LinuxContainerExecutor.java:225)

I run one simple test (not sure if valid), that is run one simple Java class as below, it reports the same issue

> /home/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.1/bin/container-executor user1 user1 0
>   application_1501214005846_0009
>   /tmp/hadoop/nm-local-dir/nmPrivate/a.token
>   /tmp/hadoop/nm-local-dir
>   /home/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.1/logs/userlogs
>   /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/bin/java -classpath
>   /home/hadoop/helloworld.jar  test.Main
>
> main : command provided 0 
>  main : user is user1
>  main :
>   requested yarn user is user1
>  Error: Could not find or load main
>   class test.Main

Comment: Can you include the code that you use when you receive the following error?

Comment: I guess it's not related to my code. I could not run the helloworld program via container-executor, at least it should not report "Could not find or load main class test.Main", since I can run helloworld as java program from command line